# Unable to start rcpbind while creating the dokcer image to mount the nfs server

Tags: docker, containers, nfs

```
Step 22/40 : RUN service rpcbind start
 
 Running in ec17bae17911
 
* Starting RPC port mapper daemon rpcbind

ln: failed to create symbolic link :: no such file or directory   

... fail

Removing intermediate container ec17bae17911
 ---> 3c995f5ee2ce
Step 23/40 : RUN service rpcbind status
 ---> Running in a01515849ba4
 * rpcbind is not running
The command '/bin/sh -c service rpcbind status' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: CmdLine
```

Comment: Appart from the fact there is obviously a non catched error in step 22, this cannot work anyway. You cannot start a service in one build step (aka`RUN`) and connect to it in the next step. The intermediate container will not exist anymore and the service won't be running. Beside that, mounting nfs during the image build looks like a very bad idea.

Comment: In general `service` (or init scripts, or `systemctl`) mostly doesn't work in Docker.  If you need to launch some kind of server, launch it directly, as a foreground process, as the container's `CMD`.

Comment: @Zeitounator  Thank you so much , so how i can implement in the Dockerfile and what is your suggestions

Comment: @DavidMaze  you mean to say that i will use CMD to start the rpcbind in our dockerfile.   I am creating this image so that i could run it as a k8s pods

Comment: My suggestion is: don't run services during build, don't mount nfs during build. Eventually do it  when your run that image as container after build if needed. Since I have no idea of what you are trying to do exactly, that's about all I'm able to give as an advice.

Comment: @Zeitounator thank you so much . I have created the nfs host server and given a path, lets say nfs server host A.B.C.D:/var , i want to mount this in my Dockerfile ,after that i will use docker image and i will create pods using that same docker image.